# How to solve non-working indexer in Eclipse CDT when using Subclipse plug-in?

Tags: eclipse-cdt, subclipse, indexer

I have never had any problems with the indexer when using Eclipse CDT. But now that I am starting to use the Subclipse plug-in, nothing works. I have been trying to disable the indexer and re-enable it again, no luck. Tried to remove the project from the workspace and checkout a new working copy, no luck. I simply get this on everything:

```
Could not find symbol 'xxxxx' in index
```

Perhaps worth mentioning is that the files in the project are svn:externals, not sure if that makes any different. Also, I see in Windows Explorer that there is only a `.project` file, shouldn't there also be a `.cproject` file?

I am using: Eclipse CDT 8.1.0 (Juno) and Subclipse 1.8.16

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact same problem with my C++ project running Juno with Subclipse 1.8.  My issue was that when I did a checkout of the repository from the SVN repository perspective, I was choosing the second option "Check out as a project in the workspace".  When I chose the first option instead, "Check out as a project configured using the New Project Wizard", it checked out my entire repository and then immediately began indexing.

The reason I chose the second option first was because it seemed like it would check out my repository whereas the first option had seemed to want to create an empty project--this turned out to be a false impression, because it will indeed check out the repository.

Comment: Correct, and after choosing the first option, choose 'C Project'

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating a new CDT project and then comparing the .xxx files and folders that are created?  Maybe you did not store all the files you need in your repository so new checkouts are not configured properly.